# For an observation of N Poisson events, what is the PMF of a Poisson parameter?

Tags: probability, bayesian, poisson-distribution, conditional-probability, distributions

If $N$ events are observed resulting from a Poisson distribution with an unknown Poisson parameter, what is the distribution of the Poisson parameter?

So if

$X \sim \text{Poisson}(\mu)$

and a sample from the distribution $X$ gives $N$ events, what is the probability distribution function for $\mu$ (given a flat prior for $\mu$)?

How would that differ from the sampling distribution of the maximum likelihood estimator for $\mu$ in a frequentist analysis?

Comment: Are you after a sampling distribution of an *estimator* for $\mu$ or are you taking a *Bayesian* approach (in which case, where's your prior?) ... please clarify the question.

Comment: I don't really understand the difference. I'm after the probability of estimates of $\mu$. If I consider a Bayesian approach, then the prior for $\mu$ is flat on 0 to infinity.

Comment: The difference is that a frequentist will treat $\mu$ as fixed but not known -- so will not engage in giving a distribution for $\mu$ at all, but do something else -- talk about the distribution of some estimator $\hat{\mu}$, such as the sample mean. Meanwhile a Bayesian will describe her uncertainty about the value of $\mu$ through a probability distribution on $\mu$ itself (before seeing data by a prior $p(\mu)$, after it by the posterior $p(\mu|x)$). If you pick a paradigm, it will indicate how to make your question clearer. We could do both but you'd word each request a little differently

Comment: Let's try a different tack: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Glen_b Ok, I see the difference now. In frequentist terms, I'm after a probability distribution of estimates $\hat{\mu}$ of the Poisson parameter $\mu$. In Bayesian terms I'm after a distribution of belief in the Poisson parameter $\mu$ resulting from the measurement. Do these give different results? Lets go with the Bayesian approach.

Comment: Note then that it won't have a pmf but a pdf, since $\mu$ is continuous (the count is discrete, but the parameter is not). The sampling distribution for $\hat{\mu}$ is discrete though. I have edited your Q in accordance with your comments above and reopened (since the question is no longer ambiguous). Please check it asks what you want and make edits if you think it should say something different.

Answer (score 1):

(I presume the $N$ events are for observing the process for 1 unit of time or at least that we want the rate per the observation interval, otherwise we have an exposure-time coming in as well.)

$f(\mu|X=N) \propto f(X=N|\mu)f(\mu)$

$\,\,\:\quad\qquad\qquad \propto \exp(-\mu)\mu^N\,,\quad \mu>0$

which is (up to a normalizing constant) the density of a $\text{Gamma}(N+1,1)$ distribution; it has mean $N+1$ and variance $N+1$.

By contrast, the sampling distribution of $\hat{\mu}$ is $\text{Poisson}(\mu)$.

A [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Confidence_interval) for $\mu$ would also be based on quantiles of a gamma distribution (specifically a $\text{Gamma}(N,1)$ as shown at the link).

Note that if you use a prior proportional to $\mu^{-1}$ -- a fairly common low-information conjugate (improper) prior for $\mu$ in the Bayesian setup -- you will get a $\text{Gamma}(N,1)$ posterior. (There's a connection between the confidence distributions in a frequentist analysis and the posteriors in a Bayesian analysis, at least when a suitably non-informative conjugate prior is applied.)